# Can I install Chatwoot on CentOS?

Tags: centos, chatwoot

Is it possible to install Chatwoot on CentOS?

I have tried with this document https://www.chatwoot.com/docs/self-hosted/deployment/linux-vm

Some error has occured. Check '/var/log/chatwoot-setup.log' for details.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Good afternoon.

According to the error message and the content of the script, it is easy to identify that it was developed to run on systems that use the "apt" package manager, usually Debian-based distributions, which is not the case with CentOS. To install it on this distribution, you would need to modify the script by replacing the command entries of "apt-get" or "apt" with the installation syntax compatible with Red Hat-based distributions like CentOS, Rocky, Fedora, etc.

I'm not sure if the package names in the CentOS repositories would be the same as in "apt" distros, but it's worth opening the script and separately and sequentially executing the commands contained in it, replacing the "apt" statements with CentOS installation syntax, which I believe is "dnf" or "yum". If any package is not found, you should search for it manually as it may have a different name in those repositories.

A second alternative, and possibly simpler, is to look for a tutorial specifically for your CentOS version. If you find one, follow it, and you should be able to succeed.